# OData Query with DateTimeOffset

Tags: linq, odata, datetimeoffset

Using LINQPad to query a OData v2 server to find records that have recently been modified and getting unexpected results:

```
// Define a DateTimeOffset to test against
DateTimeOffset testDateTimeUTC = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-180);

// Detect changes that have occurred since the test DateTimeOffset  
var changedRecords = EmpJob
.Where (e => e.lastModifiedDateTime >= testDateTimeUTC);

changedRecords.Dump();
```

Generates the query string:

```
https://api10.successfactors.com/odata/v2/EmpJob()?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge datetimeoffset'2017-05-05T00:12:18.9383091Z'
```

I get three results back, one is correct and the other two are time-stamped as:
3/10/2016 1:01 AM +00:00 and 21/12/2016 1:37 AM +00:00 which are clearly invalid.

To me it looks like a server side issue, can anyone see a problem that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a filter with a start and an end date resolved the issue.